# Unable to get BASH Script to get the version of python unless it is version 2

Tags: python, bash, for-loop

```
#!/bin/bash

for x in `find $(readlink -f /usr/local/folder/) -iregex ".*\/python[23]"`
do
  TORUN=$(echo "${x} --version")
  echo $TORUN
  TORUN2=$(eval $TORUN)
done
```

**and the results**

```
/usr/local/zz/AA_EXTERNAL/venv3/bin/python3 --version
/usr/local/zz/AA_EXTERNAL_TEST/venv3/bin/python3 --version
/usr/local/zz/API_PROXY/forapis/bin/python2 --version
Python 2.7.5
```

When I run

> /usr/local/zz/AA_EXTERNAL/venv3/bin/python3 --version

on the command line....

I get

> Python 3.6.4

Just a bit confused..

Comment: You're not echoing `TORUN2` in that snippet, and the last python printed out in your loop *is* python2. Are you sure your script isn't actually working and you're just printing the final state of `TORUN2` after the loop exits?

Comment: Note that one of the beauties of modern (1988) command substitution is that you can nest  them, hence your `for` loop can be written as `for x in $(find $(readlink ... ) -iregex "....)` (no backticks required. Cheers.

Comment: `variable=$(echo "something")` is the same as just `variable="something"`

Comment: Always quote your variables unless you have a good reason not to.